# Не работает программа (итерационный алгоритм со вложенными циклами)

Tags: c, алгоритм, функции

Реализовую данную функцию. Почему-то в переменной denominator всегда оказывается ноль что бы я ни делал.
[image: функция]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double S=0, numerator;
    int j, n, i;
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
        numerator = 1;
        for (j=1;j<=i;j++){
            numerator *= ((j+2)/10);
        }
        S += numerator/(j*pow(2,i));
    }

    printf("Result = %lf\n",&S);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Result = %lf\n",&S);`???

Comment: Что именно вас интересует?

Comment: Что там делает это `&` перед `S`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так вот здесь например:

```
((j+2)/10);
```

деление нацело при `j < 8` дает ноль, вот вы ноль и получаете.

Попробуйте

```
((j+2.0)/10.0);
```

На наличие других ошибок не смотрел.

Answer (score 1):

> На наличие других ошибок не смотрел.

А я смотрел ):

```
S += numerator/(j*pow(2,i));
```

нужно `i` вместо `j`, потому что `j` в этом месте уже больше `i`.